React batch rendering doesn't seem to work properly leading to flickering
I just started learning React and I am creating a shortening URL application to play around with the tools.  Below is the overall architecture of my program that would be helpful for the question that I would like to ask.
Both the Home and UrlForm components have access to the UrlContext dispatcher to modify the state of the urls. I am trying to implement pagination to my application, the endpoint to retrieve all the urls associated to this user is /api/urls?size=5&page=0 (I've hardcoded the pagination for now to tackle the issue.
Just to summarise:
UrlForm button -> handleSubmit -> useCreateShortUrl -> creates URL in the backend -> dispatch to update the URL -> call getURL endpoint to retrieve the latest paginated URLs -> dispatch to update the URL state in React
export default function UrlForm() {
    const [longUrl, setLongUrl] = useState(""); 
    const { createShortUrl, shortUrl, error, isLoading }= useCreateShortUrl(); 

    async function handleSubmit(e) { // event handler that will allow batch rendering
        e.preventDefault(); 

        await createShortUrl(longUrl); 
    }

import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useUrl } from "../contexts/UrlContext";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";


export function useCreateShortUrl() {
    const { token } = useAuth(); 
    const { dispatch } = useUrl(); 

    const [error, setError] = useState(null); 
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); 
    const [shortUrl, setShortUrl] = useState(""); 


    async function createShortUrl(longUrl) {
        const customHeaders = new Headers(); 
        customHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
        customHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`); 

        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: customHeaders, 
            body: JSON.stringify({longUrl}) 
        }
        try {
            const response = await fetch("api/urls", requestOptions); 

            const body = await response.json(); 
            if (!response.ok) {
                setIsLoading(false); 
                setError(body.message); 
                return;
            } 
            setError(null); 
            setIsLoading(false); 
            buildShortUrl(body.shortUrlId);  
            dispatch({ type: "CREATE_URL", payload: body }); 
            
            // updates the URL state to the correct pagination
            const secondRequestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            };
            const secondResponse = await fetch("/api/urls?size=5&page=0", secondRequestOptions)
            const secondBody = await secondResponse.json(); 
            
            if (!secondResponse.ok) {
                setError(secondBody.message);
                setIsLoading(false); 
                return; 
            }
            setError(null); 
            setIsLoading(false); 
            let urls = []
            if (secondBody._embedded) {
                urls = secondBody._embedded.urls;
            }
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_URLS', payload: urls }); 
        } catch(e) {
            // server is probably down at this point
            // response body can't pe parsed into JSON
            setIsLoading(false); 
            setError("Server is down. Please try again later."); 
        }
    }

    function buildShortUrl(shortUrlId) {
        // todo: replace with domain name, make it more flexible by retrieving from .env 
        const urlFormatter = `http://localhost:3000/urls/${shortUrlId}`
        setShortUrl(urlFormatter); 
    }

    return { createShortUrl, shortUrl, error, isLoading }; 
}

I know I can fix this issue just by removing the dispatch({ type: "CREATE_URL", payload: body });  which wouldn't send a render into the queue. But just for understanding, I'm not sure why having that would still cause the issue since React would do batch rendering after the event handler UrlForm::handleSubmit completes.
Image with debugger just before the issue
Image with debugger just after the issue (notice how there's 6 urls, that means the dispatcher caused React to render and hence now urls have 6 items)
Image at the end(notice now there's only 5 times because after calling the fetch endpoint to retrieve the paginated urls, there should only be 5 URLs and then react re-renders again to update to show the image shown there)
Side-question: How should I actually handle pagination when I create a new URL? Ideally I should only store the paginated number of URLs that's requested by the user on the current page in the state (so I don't have to store all the URLs from the database which could slow down the app) so that means I need a way to update the URL state everytime I create a URL just to maintain the correct number of URLs in the state to obey the paginated size.
